# Multiple SIDs in oracle

Tags: oracle, centos7, sid

Can we have multiple SIDs or instances in Oracle? This can be created from a sqlplus or I need a DB client. I am working with:

Centos 7.
Oracle 11g2

I have already created a default SID, but I am looking to import more databases each with its respective Instance.

Comment: No, you cannot have multiple SID per database.  But I suspect this is an x-y question and you are really trying to get at something else. Why do you think you would need another SID.  You say you want to 'import more databases'. What do you mean, exactly?  If you are talking about using 'imp' or 'impdp' to import a .dmp file, you have to already have a working database in which to import it.  A lot more detail on your end would help us get an optimal solution.

Comment: Do you just want multiple schemas in one database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO!

Oracle Database is not only "a database", it is a "database system". You can have one million databases ingested into your "one oracle database system" consisting of one SID (=instance=process+memory) and one database(name) (=datafiles,controlfiles,online redologfiles).

After Oracle Database software is in place, you can create "a database system" by

- $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus: "create database ... "
- $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbca (Database Creation Assistant), GUI or silent.

**Ingest**

You ingest (external) databases into different schemas.

```
external database A => schemaA (create user schemaA ...)
external database B => schemaB (create user schemaB ...)
etc.
```

**Security**

```
create user appA ...
grant schemaa_rw to appA; <- user appA can only access objects in schemaA being assigned role 'schemaa_rw'
create user appB ...
grant schemab_rw to appB; <- user appB can only access objects in schemaB being assigned role 'schemab_rw'
```

**The best part!**

```
Now you have ONE database system to patch, to upgrade, 
to secure, to configure, to tune - to operate.
```

**The future of Oracle Database**

If you need more isolation between your data(bases)/schemas, you can utilize a container database (CDB) from version 12c and ingest each external database into a pluggable database.

Best of luck,

Comment: Great! You gave me a model class. Thank you so much